# SqlDataAdapter Truncates DateTime to 2 Digit Year

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, datatable, sqldataadapter

I have a SQL table that I am trying to read into my application, which contains a datetime column. When I fill a DataTable using SqlDataAdapter in my application, it is truncating the year to a 2-digit year (so 1/1/1999 or 1/1/2099 both show 1/1/99).

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Using connection As New SqlConnection("...")
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM [foo]"
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, connection)

    connection.Open()
    adapter.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

Performing the same SELECT statement directly in SQL returns a datetime with a 4-digit year, so it seems like a VB problem and not a SQL problem.

How can I make sure it reads the full year and avoid a Y2K-like bug?

Comment: Date have no formats. It is how the application that you are using to see the date that decides how to present a date in a string format on your video/printer. Which application are you using to look at your data field?

Comment: In my application I am filling a DateTimePicker with a custom date format of dd/MM/yyyy, and if the date is set to 1/1/2099, the DateTimePicker is displaying the date as 1/1/1999.  I have traced this back to the initial data pull, because when I view the DataTable in the debugger after it is filled, it shows the date as 1/1/99 and my Windows regional settings are set to guess two digit years between 1930 and 2029.

Comment: What is the DataType in the database?

Comment: The datatype is datetime.

Comment: sounds you have code somewhere applying a transform.  You might [edit] your post to show the INSERT procedure; you could also add a line or two to the code posted to print a date from the datatable immediately after it has been read.

Comment: I believe I have it partially figured out.  My Windows settings are set to mm/dd/yy.  The legacy code in my application is pulling data from SQL into a DataTable.  Then it is converting the date to a string without specifying a format, so it is using my local settings (mm/dd/yy), which is truncating the year to 2 digits.  Finally, it is taking that string and setting it as the value of the DateTimePicker (which then converts the 2-digit year back to a 4-digit year)

Comment: `converting the date to a string`  there's your problem

Comment: To be clear, *if the column is in fact a DateTime* it will be a datetime variable in the DataTable.  There is no need to do anything to it - extract it from the DataTable to a DateTime variable and assign it to `DateTimePicker1.Value` which is also a DateTime type.  No need to perform any transform in any direction

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

My Windows regional settings were set to a 2-digit year.  The DataTable held the full date correctly, but before setting the value of the DateTimePicker the date held in the DataTable was converted to a String that did not specify a specific date format.

Because the format was not specified it used my local settings and truncated the first two digits off of the year.

It goes without saying, but be careful when converting dates to strings, and specify a specific format when it makes sense.  Ideally, don't convert the dates to strings in the first place (in my case it was legacy code performing this operation)!

Comment: `Ideally, don't convert the dates to strings in the first place` +1  !